# Error migrating from git to tfs: '$' at the beginning of a path

Tags: git, svn, tfs, version-control, migration

I've been trying to use [git-tf](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwi01rvhnp7QAhVMuhQKHWPsDagQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgittf.codeplex.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNEKlQnfq0QBOOIK6rj2gVJ5JQ0AYg) to migrate a fairly large GIT repository (14000 revisions) to TFS. The GIT repository is a temporary one, the original repository is in Subversion if that matters.

During the Migration one of the revisions caused an error:

> git-tf: TF10122: The path '$/TEWT/FXX/$NX001.TXT' contains a '$' at the
>   beginning of a path component. Remove the '$' and try again.

This Revision was a delete of the Folder FXX and pretty early in the overall history (9th oldest Revision). How would i go about "Fixing" this Revision so TFS accepts it?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the file name "$NX001.TXT". TFS does not support the filename start with "$". And since you mentioned that the Folder FXX had been deleted but you still get this error, I suspect that you are running the git-tf with "--deep" option. If so, there is no way to skip this error as I know.